# Trouble in downloading file with fopen in PHP

Tags: php, file, download

I want to download an sql file with fopen, my problem is that the code below will download whole sql file in addition to the html file like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...

<span style=\"font-family:tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif\">sth</span></p>
\n","media/images/","media/images/","0","en","1","0","2000-11-30","admin","sth","0","2000-12-13 00:00:00","0","","","","","12","","","","0","","73","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","","","","","0","");
INSERT INTO sctp_contents VALUES("458","","books ","","<html>
```

And the code:

```
header("Content-type: " . 'application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=/backup/".$db_bkup);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-length: $file_size");

while(!feof($handle)) {
    echo fread($handle, $file_size);
    flush();
}
fclose($handle);
die;
```

Help me, Thanks

Comment: is that the complete script for sending the file? Also - I believe that it should be `Content-Type` as opposed to `Content-type`

Comment: No dear, there are some code before that, but they are correct. No, there is no differences.

Comment: For the sake of completeness could you post the code that comes before this?

Comment: The code is copied from StackOverflow. OK

Comment: $dbhost = 'localhost'; 
    $dbuser = 'dbUsername;
    $dbpass = 'dbPassword;
 $dbname = 'dbName';

 $tables = '*';
 $link = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
 mysqli_select_db($dbname,$link);
 mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

 //get all of the tables
 if($tables == '*')
 {
  $tables = array();
  $result = mysqli_query('SHOW TABLES');
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
  {
   $tables[] = $row[0];
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
 }
 $return='';
 //cycle through
 foreach($tables as $table)
 {
  $result = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM

Comment: '.$table);
  $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);

  $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
  $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
  $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

  for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
  {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
   {
    $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
    for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
    {
     $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
     $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
     if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
     if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= '

Comment: ,'; }
    }
    $return.= ");\n";
   }
  }
  $return.="\n\n\n";
 }

 //save file
 $db_date = jDateTime::date('Y-m-d', false, false);
 $db_bkup = 'db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql';
 
 $handle = fopen('backup\\'.$db_bkup,'w+');
 fwrite($handle,$return);
 $file_size = filesize('backup\\'.$db_bkup);
 fclose($handle);
 
 $handle = fopen('backup\\'.$db_bkup,'r');

 $stmt = $this->model->_query('INSERT INTO sctp_backup VALUES("", '."'".$db_bkup."'".', '."'".$db_date."'".', 1)');
 
 header("Content-type: " . 'application/octet-stream');
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment

Comment: ; filename=/backup/".$db_bkup);
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header("Content-length: $file_size");

 while(!feof($handle)) {
  echo fread($handle, $file_size);
  flush();
 }
 fclose($handle);

Answer (score 0):

Afer piecing together the rest of the code into a readable format I cannot see anything in particular that looks amiss - the only thing which, to me, looks odd is `jDateTime` ~ this might be a function within a later version of PHP or a custom function I don't know but it looks odd.

Other than that perhaps use `ob_clean` to ensure there are no characters output before you begin the download and use the correct headers.

```
ob_clean();
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=/backup/{$db_bkup}");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: {$file_size}");

while( !feof( $handle ) ) {
    echo fread( $handle, $file_size );
    flush();
}
fclose( $handle );
die;
```

Comment: It partially worked, now there is no html before that but middle and after...Thanks

Comment: No Dear RamRaider, there is no error, I think it gets them from some modules, or some other files that are included. It's an mvc structured cms, and I don't know where the possible includes are. Again thank you.